# odoo[QWEB] can not call method from template

Tags: templates, odoo-9, qweb

I try to call method of model from template and receive an error:

```
QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_session_data'" while evaluating
'testmodule.get_session_data()'
```

model has such view:

```
class testmodule(models.Model):
    _name = 'testmodule'

    def get_session_data(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return u'READING'
```

Security settings:

```
access_testmodule,testmodule,model_testmodule,,1,1,1,1
```

Qweb template:

```
<t t-esc="testmodule.get_session_data()" />
```

What am I doing wrong? If I try to call method from website model all work fine. I want use my own classes and methods from them. How can I do it?

UPD:
templates.xml:

```
<template id="website.user_navbar" inherit_id="website.layout" groups="base.group_user">
    <xpath expr="//body/div['id=wrawrap']" position="before">
        <div style="background-color: #000800; height:110px;color: red">
            | <t t-raw="website.is_user()" /> |<br />
            | <t t-esc="testmodule.get_session_data()" /> |
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: testmodule is not defined. You probably need to call get_session_data from JavaScript and then render the result. Can you show more of your xml code?

Comment: I added update to post.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you look at the method _prepare_qcontext (odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py), you will see that the variable website is defined there, and that's why the call to website.is_user() works. So I think you may need to override _prepare_qcontext and add an instance of testmodule to its returning object, so you can call get_session_data from your xml.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for answer!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, if you don't mind marking it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the method `_prepare_qcontext` (odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py), you will see that the variable `website` is defined there, and that's why the call to `website.is_user()` works. So I think you may need to override `_prepare_qcontext` and add an instance of `testmodule` to its returning object, so you can call `get_session_data` from your xml.